# String replace with exact match word based on a key present in a queryurl

Tags: java

When someone get rest method called by using below url hit the controllerMethod.
For example URL string like:

```
String queryurl=http://localhost:8081/servcie/details?id=101&type=124;
String changedQueryUrl=null;
@GetMapping(value = "details")
public MyModel controllerMethod(@RequestParam Map<String, String> customQuery,HttpServletRequest request) {

//i have to replace words "id" with rollNo and "type" with datatype
// so that i have done below sample code

 for (  Entry<String, String> entry : customQuery.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals("id")) {
      changedQueryUrl= request.getQueryString().replaceAll("\\bid\\b", "rollNo");                    
    }
    else if (entry.getKey().equals("type")) {
      changedQueryUrl= request.getQueryString().replaceAll("\\btype\\b", "datatype");
    }
  }
}
```

when i am printing  changedQueryUrl only one of word is replacing other word is not replacing.

I want to print the output like with exact matching words

```
changedQueryUrl=http://localhost:8081/servcie/details?rollNo=101&datatype=124
```

Comment: Which one is replaced and which one not?

Comment: In place of  id i want rollNo and type with dataType

Comment: @Sriram I guess if you are getting any result with your code, we would like to know what is the result that you are currently obtaining. Also why are you replacing that in the for loop and not outside? With that you just doesn't have to pass through the if's conditions.

Comment: @Brank Thanks for to think again myself in logic.I just did request.getQueryString().replace("id","rollNo").replace("type","dataType"). Not required for loop here. I am getting expected result

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` returns a new copy of the original string, so the first replace don't change the original String `request.queryString()`. The second `replaceAll` works on `request.queryString()` which has no effect because you need to work with the result of `replaceAll`.

And don't use `request.queryString()` anymore in your loop, if you want to make your code working you can assign `changedQueryUrl= request.getQueryString();` before the loop and use `changedQueryUrl.replaceAll(...)` instead of `request.getQueryString().replaceAll(...)`.

Or just do

```
String queryurl = "http://localhost:8081/servcie/details?id=101&type=124;";
String queryRes = queryurl.replaceAll("\\bid\\b", "rollNo").replaceAll("\\btype\\b", "datatype");
```